# How do I run python 2.7.5 through sublime text 2?

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation, sublimetext2

My sublime REPL is currently running python 2.6.1, I have no idea how seeing as I have never downloaded it. I am trying to install matplotlib and keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

So I thought installing python 2.7.5 would make this work instead, how do I do this?

Comment: You don't. Sublime's Python is unrelated to your installed Python distribution. It's bundled with the text editor because Sublime Text's plugins are written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> to go to the console, you are using the internal version of Python that comes included with Sublime Text 2. You cannot run external modules with this version, it is static.

If you want to use your system Python, install [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation), then install [SublimeREPL](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeREPL). By default, this will use the version of Python that comes first on your system's `PATH`. Once running, as long as you've properly installed `matplotlib`, you should be able to import and use it within SublimeREPL with no problems.

Comment: How do I properly install matplotlib?

Comment: By visiting their [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html) and following the instructions